# How to do queue of messages that shows in one div after delay?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to implement queue which elements after shown with delay fadeOut and split out from array? This funcionallity should be provide message shows one after another in the same div even when `showAlertBarMessages()` is invoked many diffrent times like in FIFO. For now I can't clean shown elements. I spend one day and I don't know.

My current solution and working example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZtY38/:

```
var msgQueue = [];

var i = 1;
$('#add-msg').click(function () {
    msgQueue.push("Message number " + i);
    showAlertBarMessages();
    i++;
});

function showAlertBarMessages() {
    msgQueue.map(function (msg, idx) {
        return function () {
            var el = $('<div />').html(msg).addClass('msg').insertBefore('#msg-sequentially');
            $(el).click(function () {
                console.log("fadeOut and remove from queue");
            });
            if (idx > 0) {
                return el.delay(2000).fadeIn(500).promise()
            } else {
                return el.fadeIn(500).promise()
            }
        };
    }).reduce(function (cur, next) {
        console.log("alredy shown fadeOut and remove from queue");
        return cur.then(next);
    }, $().promise());
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="msg-sequentially"></div>
<button id="add-msg">Add next message</button>
```

Instead `insertBefore` should be `append` to `#msg-sequentially` but this doesn't work.
Or is there any completely other approach for this solution?

Comment: Your problem looks interesting but what does "This funcionallity should be provide message shows one after another in the same div even when showAlertBarMessages() is invoked many diffrent times like in FIFO. For now I can't clean shown elements." mean?? I read 3-4 times and I don't get what you're looking to do.

Comment: Sorry if my english is not correct. I'll display messages in one div not in the same time but one after another regardless of the messages number. Message that is already shown should be removed after delay and fadeOut.

Comment: And how's the counter supposed to work? When I press the button, what should happen that's not currently happening?

Comment: Button imitate only function that adds new message to queue, dificult is that it invoke each time showAlertBarMessages() function, even when all messages are not shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try that and see if it's fitting your needs:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZtY38/1/)

```
function showAlertBarMessages() {
    var msg = msgQueue[0];
    if (!$('#msg-sequentially').find(':visible').length) {
         var el = $('<div />').html(msg).addClass('msg').appendTo('#msg-sequentially');
        el.fadeIn(500).promise().done(function () {
            $(this).delay(2000).fadeOut().promise().done(function () {
                $(this).remove();
                msgQueue.splice(0,1);
                if(msgQueue.length) showAlertBarMessages();
            });
        });
    }
}
```